# ¿Cómo ordenar por edad dentro de un rango determinado? MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Quiero obtener los resultados de las personas que se encuentren dentro de un rango de edad concreto, por ejemplo entre [20 y 30] años.

Para ello estoy haciendo esta consulta.

```
select ID from users where COMUNIDAD='Andalucía' AND PROVINCIA='Jaén'
AND (NOMBRE regexp '^a|A' OR APELLIDO regexp '^a|A') 
ORDER BY EDAD DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Pero esta parte no está correctamente formulada (faltaría seleccionar el rango de edad especificado).

```
 ORDER BY EDAD DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

La tabla sería mas o menos así:

```
EL FORMATO DE LA TABLA ES MAS O MENOS ASI:

ID  COMUNIDAD  PROVINCIA  NOMBRE    APELLIDO      EDAD    
1   Andalucía  Jaén       Rocio     Rodríguez      18  
2   Andalucía  Jaén       Pedro     Navarro        25 
3   Andalucía  Jaén       Juán      García         30
```

Aporto el SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  `COMUNIDAD` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PROVINCIA` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  `EDAD`  tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `COMUNIDAD`, `PROVINCIA`, `NOMBRE` `EDAD`) VALUES
(87, 'Andalucía', 'Jaén', 'Rocio', 'Rodríguez', '18'),
(88, 'Andalucía', 'Jaén', 'Pedro', 'Navarro',   '25'),
(89, 'Andalucía', 'Jaén', 'Juán',  'García',    '30');




ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);



ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=94;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Pero... en tu modelo de datos, Juan García tendrá 31 años mañana o cualquiera de estos días y sin embargo seguirá apareciendo en la consulta y el martes alguien cumplirá 20 años y no aparecerá. ¿Cómo se controla eso? ¿Por qué no capturaste mejor la fecha de nacimiento para calcular la edad en base a ese dato (así sabrás siempre la edad que tiene cada cual, ¿no?)? Nunca vi que fuera correcto guardar la edad como un dato fijo en una base de datos, no tiene ningún sentido.

Comment: Si verás, el registro solo va a  durar unos pocos dias o semanas... en cualquier caso si durara mas tiempo el usuario puede cambiarlo

Comment: Aún así, es mejor usar la fecha de nacimiento, porque de ese modo evitas que el dato sea manipulado *a mano*. Ahorras trabajo y evitas errores. Supongamos que alguien vaya a actualizar el dato, y ponga algo como:  `311` en la edad, en vez de `31`... Yo me lo pienso mil veces antes de guardar un campo calculado en una base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En MySQL tienes una función mas sencilla para lo que quieres lograr, en este caso seria **BETWEEN** la cual te permitira mostrar solamente los datos que se encuentren en el rango que le indiques, en tu caso y con el ejemplo que diste seria:

```
WHERE EDAD BETWEEN 20 AND 30;
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto muchas gracias... en mi caso tuve que que hacerlo así para que funcionara **AND EDAD BETWEEN 20 AND 30;**

Comment: @IvánRodríguez me alegra que te haya funcionado.

Comment: ¿Sabrías como hacer para que se ordenen de mayor a menor y viceversa?

Comment: para hacer eso tienes que usar `ORDER BY` y elegir si será `ASC` o `DESC` @IvánRodríguez

Comment: ¿No se puede combinar ORDER BY con BETWEEN de alguna forma? Es que me interesa seleccionar el rango y además ordenarlo. Si no se puede me quedo con BETWEEN... en mi caso le doy mas importacia a seleccionar el rango... pero hacer las dos cosas estaría genial

Comment: Si se puede :-)... La cosa queda algo así: **ORDER BY (EDAD BETWEEN 20 AND 30) DESC**  Gracias a los dos!! Saludos!!

Comment: Me equivoqué, lo que escribí antes no funciona... :-( aunque tampoco da error... seguiré intentandolo a ver si lo consigo... si se os ocurre como a hecerlo soy todo oidos

Comment: AND EDAD BETWEEN 20 AND 30 ORDER BY EDAD DESC quizas asi funcione.

Comment: Perfecto!! Muchas gracias otra vez!!